# How can I close the clipboard in Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I’m preparing an Excel file to collect data from external users.

Users will have other Excel files open and they will also have the clipboard open in those files. This will, by default it seems, result in the clipboard being open in my file.

Is there a way to automatically close the clipboard, if it is open, with VBA code when users open the file? (I only want to close it. It doesn’t have to be emptied before doing so.)

My concern is that the clipboard takes up too much space in the left margin. I want the screen to have maximum width when the file is opened.

The code should work for Excel 2013 and later versions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want this:

```
application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = False
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!